# Inserting into DB the association established in Doctrine/Symfony 4

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

My user class in Symfony 4:

```
namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;

    /**
     * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\UserRepository")
     * @UniqueEntity(fields={"email"}, message="There is already an account with this email")
     */
    class User implements UserInterface
    {
        /**
         * @ORM\Id()
         * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
         * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
         */
        private $id;

    // ... rest of the User Entity
    }
```

I created another entity called "Creator" like so:

```
// src/Entity/Creator.php
namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\ProductRepository")
 */
class Creator
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\User", inversedBy="creator")
     */
    private $user;


    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function createCreator($userid)
    {
        $this->user->id = $userid;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getUser(): ?User
    {
        return $this->user;
    }

    // ... getter and setter methods
}
```

The association between the two is when the user registers as a "creator" (outside of the context of just registering as a "regular user"), the insert associates the creator with the user.

Inserting into the DB is like so:

```
$user    = new User();
$creator = new Creator();
$form    = $this->createForm(CreatorRegistrationForm::class, [$user, $creator]);
$form->handleRequest($request);

if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
    $user
        ->setEmail($form->get('email')->getData())
        ->setPassword(
                $passwordEncoder->encodePassword(
                    $user,
                    $form->get('password')->getData()
                )
            )
            ->setFirstName($form->get('firstname')->getData())
            ->setLastName($form->get('lastname')->getData())
            ->setBirthday($form->get('birthday')->getData());

            $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $entityManager->persist($user);
            $entityManager->flush(); //This insert is successful :)

            $userID = $user->getId();

            $creator->createCreator($userID);

            $entityManager->persist($creator);
            $entityManager->flush();
            // This does nothing.
            // Can you only persist/flush once? If so, what is the right syntax?

            return $guardHandler->authenticateUserAndHandleSuccess(
                $user,
                $request,
                $authenticator,
                'main' // firewall name in security.yaml
            );
        }
```

Is this the correct way to create an association in the DB via doctrine? Still trying to understand how associations work. Do you have to explicitly state the associations similarly to what is above?  This returns an error of `Warning: Creating default object from empty value` and it points this:

```
public function createCreator($userid)
{        
    $this->user->id = $userid; //this here is what the error points to.

    return $this;    
}
```

What's the right approach to doing this?

Comment: No, this is not the correct way to generate meaningful relations with Doctrine.  At the risk of being unkind, you are not even close.  All I can really suggest it going through the [example in the docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/associations.html) set by step.  But you might want to start with how to use forms with entities as much of that code in your question is either wrong or unnecessary.

Comment: I mean, you can still be kind, but helpful too. I saw this document but forgot about it. I'll go through it again.

Comment: I would remove most of the code related to form handling from your question. Your question is either about form handling and the form component, or about Doctrine ORM. It looks like it's about the latter, hence my answer. _How_ you get the data to persist via doctrine is not really relevant, and cleaning this up would result in a higher quality question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doctrine expects `Creator->user` to be an object of the `User` class.

So you'd probably need a `Creator::setUser(User)` method, and do something like this:

```
//...
$entityManager->persist($user);
$creator->setUser($user);
$entityManager->persist($creator);

$entityManaer->flush();
```